# Chart.js with Vue3: update() fails, gives infinite recursion errors

Tags: vuejs3, chart.js

I am stumped on a problem with **[Vue3](https://vuejs.org)** and the excellent **[Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org)** library.

Initially creating a chart with data values works great. But for this app, chart values must be updated dynamically. According to the [Chart.js examples](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/border-radius.html), this is as simple as calling the `update()` method on the chart instance (e.g., `chart.update()`) after updating the chart's data object.

However, this appears totally broken. It does not update, and results in the following warning and error (with slight variation in error description depending on browser)...

`[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler`

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` (Chrome)

`Uncaught InternalError: too much recursion` (Firefox)

I have created a super-simple codesandbox.io example [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/chart-js-vue3-basic-example-c8qjgp?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfgu5ni00072a687l4o5ixy%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfgu5ni00022a68udimspa8%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfgu5ni00042a68d0cy8pj0%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfgu5ni00062a68xm4b94e9%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqfgu5ni00022a68udimspa8%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfgu5ni00022a68udimspa8%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqfgy0nm00hv2a68noktbny0%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfgu5ni00012a681vleta74%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.codesandbox%252Ftasks.json%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfgy0nm00hv2a68noktbny0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clqfgu5ni00062a68xm4b94e9%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfgu5ni00062a68xm4b94e9%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfgu5ni00052a6835sl49p9%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522npm%2520run%2520dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqfgu5ni00052a6835sl49p9%2522%257D%252C%2522clqfgu5ni00042a68d0cy8pj0%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfgu5ni00042a68d0cy8pj0%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqfgu5ni00032a68o8uir2pu%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522npm%2520run%2520dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqfgu5ni00032a68o8uir2pu%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) to demonstrate the issue. Note, to see the error you must view the console window by clicking the "Preview Console" button at the top-right of the codesandbox.io render window.

**Interesting data point:** Vue3 and Chart.js are latest versions. Out of curiosity I progressively downgraded Chart.js and discovered `update()` starts working at Chart.js@2.9.4.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

(I am aware of the [vue-chartjs](https://vue-chartjs.org) helper wrapper, but for multiple reasons it is not a good option.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `shallowRef` around the chartInstance.

`import { shallowRef } from "vue";`

So this `chartInstance: null,` changed to `chartInstance: shallowRef(null),`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas ref="chartCanvas"></canvas>
    <button @click="updateChartData">Update Chart Data</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from "chart.js/auto"; // Import Chart.js
import { shallowRef } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "MyChart",
  data() {
    return {
      chartInstance: shallowRef(null),
      chartData: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "# of Votes",
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
              "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
              "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
            ],
            borderColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
              "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
              "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart();
  },
  methods: {
    renderChart() {
      const ctx = this.$refs.chartCanvas.getContext("2d");

      this.chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "bar",
        data: this.chartData,
        options: {
          // Chart options
        },
      });
    },
    updateChartData() {
      const newData = this.generateRandomData();
      this.chartInstance.data.datasets[0].data = newData;
      this.chartInstance.update();
    },
    generateRandomData() {
      return Array.from({ length: 6 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 20));
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/chart-js-vue3-basic-example-forked-t737cv?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FMyChart.vue%3A17%2C19